# force change password in docker of archlinux but failed

Tags: docker, archlinux, openssh

I've setup a archlinux with openssh login docker image, I force user to change password at first login. But the change password process will stop for "Authentication failure". As normal real machine arch linux, it will show "New password:" prompt, my testing process for real Arch Linux box is

```
# chage -d0 myuser
# ssh -l myuser localhost
myuser@localhost's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Change password for myuser.
Current password:
New password:    <- in Docker, it won't show this
Retype newpassword:
```

My test process of docker

```
docker run -i -t --rm base/archlinux /bin/bash
```

Run the following command inside docker

```
pacman -Sy --noconfirm openssh
ssh-keygen -A
useradd -m myuser
echo -e "pass\npass" | passwd myuser
chage -d0 myuser
/usr/bin/sshd -D &
ssh -l myuser localhost
```

Comment: provide Dockerfile and put here lines that produce the error

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/base/archlinux/

Comment: This seems to be an archlinux issue.  Doing the equivalent with `debian:latest` works ok.

Comment: @Paul confirm this running `Alpine` as well.